# How to access a python object from a previous HTTP request?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, web-applications, flask, httprequest

I have some confusion about how to design an asynchronous part of a web app. My setup is simple; a visitor uploads a file, a bunch of computation is done on the file, and the results are returned. Right now I'm doing this all in one request. There is no user model and the file is  not stored on disk.

I'd like to change it so that the results are delivered in two parts. The first part comes back with the request response because it's fast. The second part might be heavy computation and a lot of data, so I want it to load asynchronously, whenever it's done. What's a good way to do this?

---

Here are some things I do know about this. Usually, asynchronicity is done with ajax requests. The request will be to some route, let's say `/results`. In my controller, there'll be a method written to respond to `/results`. But this method will no longer have any information from the previous request, because HTTP is stateless. To get around this, people pass info through the request. I could either pass all the data through the request, or I could pass an id which the controller would use to look up the data somewhere else.

My data is a big python object (a pandas `DataFrame`). I don't want to pass it through the network. If I use an id, the controller will have to look it up somewhere. I'd rather not spin up a database just for these short durations, and I'd also rather not convert it out of python and write to disk. How else can I give the ajax request access to the python object across requests?

My only idea so far is to have the initial request trigger my framework to render a second route, `/uuid/slow_results`. This would be served until the ajax request hits it. I think this would work, but it feels pretty ad hoc and unnatural.

Is this a reasonable solution? Is there another method I don't know? Or should I bite the bullet and use one of the aforementioned solutions?

(I'm using the web framework Flask, though this question is probably framework agnostic.

PS: I'm trying to get better at writing SO questions, so let me know how to improve it.)

Answer (score 0):

So *if* your app is only being served by one Python process, you could just have a global object that's a map from ids to DataFrames, but you'd also need some way of expiring them out of the map so you don't leak memory.

So if your app is running on multiple machines, you're screwed. If your app is just running on one machine, it might be sitting behind apache or something and then apache might spawn multiple Python processes and you'd still be screwed? I think you'd find out by doing ps aux and counting instances of python.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing to a temporary file or database are fine choices in general, but if you don't like either in this case and don't want to set up e.g. Celery just for this one thing, then [multiprocessing.connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients) is probably the tool for the job. Copying and lightly modifying from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch11s07.html), the box running your webserver (or another, if you want) would have another process that runs this:

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import traceback


RESULTS = dict()


def do_thing(data):
    return "your stuff"


def worker_client(conn):
    try:
        while True:
            msg = conn.recv()
            if msg['type'] == 'answer':  # request for calculated result
                answer = RESULTS.get(msg['id'])
                conn.send(answer)
                if answer:
                    del RESULTS[msg['id']]
            else:
                conn.send("doing thing on {}".format(msg['id']))
                RESULTS[msg['id']] = do_thing(msg)
    except EOFError:
        print('Connection closed')


def job_server(address, authkey):
    serv = Listener(address, authkey=authkey)
    while True:
        try:
            client = serv.accept()
            worker_client(client)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_server(('', 25000), authkey=b'Alex Altair')
```

and then your web app would include:

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Client


client = Client(('localhost', 25000), authkey=b'Alex Altair')

def respond(request):
    client.send(request)
    return client.recv()
```

Design could probably be improved but that's the basic idea.